Can I initialize a replica server without locking the master server during an initial backup/restore phase?
Context
I want to set up a mariadb replica server, which would replicate an existing live mariadb server -- the goal is to have a hot standby replica of the existing server.
My understanding
Following the Setting Up Replication guide from the documentation, at the "Getting the Master's Binary Log Co-ordinates" paragraph, I read (the list describes more steps, I kept the 3 I have a question about, emphasis is also mine) :


On the master, flush and lock all tables by running FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK. Keep this session running - exiting it will release the lock.
[...]
Now, with the lock still in place, copy the data from the master to the slave. See Backup, Restore and Import for details on how to do this.
Once the data has been copied, you can release the lock on the master by running UNLOCK TABLES.


This procedure suggests to basically suspend activity (write activity at least) on the master database to initialize the database on the replica side.
My question
Is there a way to initialize the replica without locking the master database for a complete dump + load of the data ?
for example, if a tool was able to:

take a backup of the (live) master database,
some extra information (things like: initial value of the GTID on the master server, some information from the binary logs during the backup),
and create a consistent combination of database + gtid on the replica,

I could then instruct the replica to start its replication with MASTER_USE_GTID = slave_pos.
xtrabackup and mariabackup claim to be able to backup a database from a live server, are they also able to set a correct synchronization point to start a replica from that backup ?
We are working with MariaDB 10.11.6 on a debian bookworm system.

The Setting up a Replica with Mariabackup article on the MariaDB Knowledgebase describes the process of setting up a replica with mariadbackup.

Backup the database and prepare it

$ mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/var/mariadb/backup/ \
   --user=mariabackup --password=mypassword


Copy the backup to the new replica

$ rsync -avP /var/mariadb/backup dbserver2:/var/mariadb/backup


Restore the backup on the new replica and adjust file permissions

$ mariabackup --copy-back --target-dir=/var/mariadb/backup/
$ chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/


Create a replication user on the primary, if necessary

CREATE USER 'repl'@'dbserver2' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.*  TO 'repl'@'dbserver2';


Configure the new replica

The starting position for the replication can be found by inspecting the xtrabackup_binlog_info file where the last value is the GTID position of the backup.
# The last value (0-1-2) is the GTID position
$ cat xtrabackup_binlog_info
mariadb-bin.000096 568 0-1-2

Then replication can be set up with:
-- This value is from the xtrabackup_binlog_info
SET GLOBAL gtid_slave_pos = "0-1-2";

-- This configures replication
CHANGE MASTER TO 
   MASTER_HOST="dbserver1", 
   MASTER_PORT=3306, 
   MASTER_USER="repl",  
   MASTER_PASSWORD="password", 
   MASTER_USE_GTID=slave_pos;

-- This starts replication
START SLAVE;

